# TYK Dashboard and Gateway Payload

Tags: linux, api, docker, devops, tyk

Hi everyone I'm working for create connectivity TYK Gateway and TYK Dashboard and create user with bootstrap.sh script .

So after all those things when I run the script it returns Python JSON Error .

My Dashboard Environment Variables

```
  TYK_DB_LICENSEKEY=LICENSE_KEY
  TYK_DB_TYKAPI_HOST=tykgw.domain.com
  TYK_DB_LISTENPORT=3000
  TYK_DB_TYKAPI_PORT=8080
  TYK_DB_MONGOURL=gcloud-internal-mongo           

TYK_DB_REDISHOST=redis
```

My Gateway Env Variables

```
  TYK_GW_STORAGE_HOST=redis
  TYK_GW_ALLOWINSECURECONFIGS=true

  TYK_GW_DBAPPCONFOPTIONS_CONNECTIONSTRING=\
            http://db.domain.com.:3000

  TYK_GW_POLICIES_POLICYCONNECTIONSTRING=\
    http://db.domain.com.:3000
```

This is the tyk gateway logs :

```
level=warning msg="Unknown notification command: \"OrgAdded\""
```

How I can solve this bootstrap.sh error also connectivity problem between Dashboard and Gateway .

Please Help !

Answer (score 0):

The error message would have helped to troubleshoot the issue. Also, the gateway and dashboard logs if present could show what the issue is.

However, examining the [conf files](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk_quickstart) or [env variables](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk-pro-docker-demo/tree/master/confs) are the most likely causes for connection issues between the dashboard and gateway.

You could also check out the latest [tky-demo](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk-demo) repro.